# jQuery: cannot call click event on select when click another div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select id="manufacturer">
            <option value="0">Select a manufacturer</option>
            <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
</select>
<div class="select-widget"></div>
```

And I try to call click method for select when I press `.select-widget` div, but nothing happens!

```
$('select').next().click(function(){
                            $(this).prev().click();
});
```

P.S. trigger('click') works the same way, it does not make dropdown event!

so how can i trigger dropdown event of select when i click .select-widget div?
Plz help someone with this issue!

Comment: drop down has change event

Comment: you want to change dropdown selection on div click?

Comment: the select click event will not open the select on the ui if thats what your aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but does this solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/p4s6z/2/

HTML:

```
<select id="manufacturer">
    <option value="0">Select a manufacturer</option>
    <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' class='select-widget' onclick='alert("ok")'></input>
```

Javascript:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    $('.select-widget').click();
});
```

**EDIT** updated to use `on`, thanks @jme11

Comment: Please, please don't suggest live it's been deprecated and removed since 1.7.  The on() method is the proper way to bind events.

Comment: no, conversely,  i need to call dropdown event of select when i click on .select-widget!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what functionality you're looking for, but you can't get the same reaction using .click() in jQuery as you would get from actually clicking on page.  The .click() jQuery function only 'clicks' the element in the sense that it triggers any on click events.

Comment: ok, how can i trigger dropdown event of select when i click .select-widget div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the trigger method.  Try this:

```
$('.select-widget').on('click', function(){
   $('#manufacturer').trigger('click');
});

$('#manufacturer').on('click', function(){
    $(this).val('Brother');
});
```

Just so you understand, the click() method in jQuery is an event handler that is shorthand for onclick.  The trigger method will trigger an event on the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your code requires you to trigger events it probably needs to be refactored.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select').on('change',function(){
        $('.select-widget').submit();
    });

    $('.select-widget').on('submit',function(){
        alert('submitted!');
    });

})
```